# Single word for driving slowly?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word that means to drive a vehicle slowly, especially in a way that is unexpected or looks out of place eg. blown tire on a highway or race track and carefully trying to drive out of the way. I know the word "cruise" but this has too positive connotations, since you wouldn't use cruise to describe a driver who was cruising slowly away due to being in danger or having damage to their vehicle, since it sounds like they either do not care or are even enjoying the problem.

The only other options I had considered is to add an adjective to the driving eg. driving slowly, or similarly describing the speed of the vehicle's movement eg. vehicle moved at snail's pace, but I am hoping for a better alternative?

Comment: Could you please provide us with a sample sentence as required by the single-word-request tag you have chosen?

Comment: 'The car limped along to the nearest garage' uses a verb describing the progress of the vehicle rather than the driving process. 'He nursed the car along' is another acceptable metaphorical broadening. Please say if either of these is satisfactory, and I'll convert to an 'answer'.

Comment: At Edwin, sorry, but I had already written that up and was only waiting for the OP to supply the sample sentence.

Comment: This post lacks a sample sentence as required by the SWR tag, but is fairly clear in the examples from the second para.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Slow moving cars **crawl**:

> [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crawl): to move or progress slowly or laboriously
>
> > traffic crawling along at 10 miles an hour

See also this example:

> ... as the car crawled through a five-mile backup on the New Jersey Turnpike. — [Fly Away Home: A Novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=g3ipUCWw0E8C&pg=PA10&dq=%22car%20crawled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3run7mrftAhVfGVkFHch3Cr04FBDoATAFegQIARAC#v=onepage&q=%22car%20crawled%22&f=false)

Comment: You beat me to it! That seems like the obvious answer.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question in the title.

Comment: Also seen in "crawler lanes" for very heavy vehicles on steep hills.

Comment: Spot on; see also the "crawler gear" or "crawler ratio" on heavy vehicles - a gear ratio so low that it will only allow the vehicle to "crawl" along at very low speed, in circumstances such as steep hills (@BrianDrummond) or to get a very heavy load moving prior to selecting first gear.

Comment: Not to mention [kerb-crawling](https://britishslang.co.uk/slang/kerb-crawling) !!!  Note to non-British readers - make sure you read the definition before using this word!

Comment: I don't think "crawl" actually implies some trouble with a car as asked in the question if used for a sentence about public roads. It's used way too often for just slow moving traffic so one would likely need the rest of the sentence to clarify that slow speed was due to condition of the car and not due to rush hour. Should be fine for race track so - there is never slow speed driving unless there some major problem...

Comment: Possibly worth noting: If I'm not mistaken, while this word is pretty commonly used for this, it's not technically defined that way per se.  On the one hand, this meaning is used for anything/anyone going particularly slowly, and on the other hand, it's also slang.

Answer (score 34):

It might sound like personification, but this could work...

***limp***

> to proceed slowly or with difficulty

> Ex. The ship limped back to port

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/limp)

In your case, you could say...

> The car *limped* off the track/road.

> The car *limped* down the track.

Comment: Indeed, some cars can go into "limp mode" or "limp-home mode" when they sense a failure or anomaly. http://www.fordproblems.com/electronic-throttle-body/

Comment: This is the best answer for OP's example of a race car with a blown tire.

Comment: *hobbled* would be a good synonym here with slightly less bipedal terminology.

Comment: @stevesliva As a native English speaker in Canada who reads a lot, I'd like to point out that I only just learned that "hobble" could be used in a non-transitive, non-state-of-being "to walk lamely; limp." form now, when I went looking after you implied its existence ...so whether it's suitable will probably depend on your region. (i.e. If this weren't the English SE, my first impulse would have been to correct you for using English incorrectly... not that it would have prevented me from checking a dictionary first.)

Comment: @ssokolow - [It's a synonym. And doesn't appear to be a rare one.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hobbled%2Climped&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).   There is a specific connotation for horses that could mean it's more likely to mean animals walking awkwardly.

Comment: @stevesliva I did check the dictionary. I'm just saying that, despite being a voracious reader, that meaning was so alien to my experience where I live that I thought it was a mistake at first, so it's clearly not equally well-known everywhere.

Comment: This is definitely also correct if emphasizing the fact that the vehicle is damaged in some way

Comment: @ssokolow No specific examples, but I feel like I've seen this usage in both British and US writing...especially in a phrase like "s/he hobbled along" or "hobbled down to the store". I'm  really surprised it would be so unusual in Canada.

Comment: @stevesliva Hate to tell you but there's also a human-specific historical connotation that refers to permanent maiming of the legs as punishment or torture. (You really don't want to know...but it definitely results in the visual of someone who can't move very quickly or who limps.)

Comment: Right, but when Tolkien, Dickens and Melville use it, it’s pretty clear what they mean.  Someone is walking awkwardly.   I guess this should have been it’s own answer.  I thought it was a fairly mundane synonym for *limp* that didn’t specifically refer to an injury favoring one leg.

Comment: @user3067860 Interesting. My intuition accepts the former of your examples, but not the latter. Anyway, this is getting too conversational, so I'll bow out now.

Answer (score 16):

How about *puttering*.

[Definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/putter)

2. to move or go in a specified manner with ineffective action or little energy or purpose: to putter about the house on a rainy day.
3. to move or go slowly or aimlessly; loiter.

"Putter" is also the sound of an engine running at low speed.

I have heard it used to describe driving slowly.  [Here's an example](https://www.reddit.com/r/snowrunner/comments/jupxig/just_puttering_down_the_road/)

Comment: Puttering is usually enjoyable, so it doesn't fit in with some of the specifics. Also puttering is usually voluntary, you could speed up--you just don't want to because you're enjoying going slowly.

Answer (score 14):

Merriam Webster:

> **dawdle** verb, intransitive
>
> **2 : to move lackadaisically** *"I don't want you dawdling while you making deliveries for Mrs. Ford."*— Connie Porter

Comment: Humans sure dawdle, but could the same be said of or extended to vehicles? It sounds a jot unnatural to me, @Greybeard :)

Comment: Another good choice but tends to be used more of an individual car, not traffic in general with its thousands of cars.

Comment: @user405662 and Henry: Super fuels - worth the difference? - Page 2 - forums.flyer.co.uk › viewtopic *For example if I get stuck in traffic too much or get stuck behind traffic dawdling well below the speed limit when it is safe to do the speed limit,* -- Even aircraft dawdle *LANDING WITH THE RUNWAY OCCUPIED - FLYER Forums *"... safe on a long runway like Kemble's but this is an airmanship issue. Following traffic getting too close and landing traffic dawdling to vacate*

Comment: Focussing on "English english" usage, "dawdling" would certainly be my selection for a single driver going slowly by choice. "Limp" implies a fault, "crawl" is more often applied to an entire traffic flow ("traffic was crawling on account of the roadworks").

Answer (score 7):

You could say that the car is **pootling** along.

[To pootle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pootle) is ‘to wander or ramble in a leisurely, indirect, or aimless manner, such as by walking or driving; to potter’.  (It's common only in British English, apparently.)

However, while that matches the headline question, it does *not* imply care or caution — the reverse, if anything.

Comment: Kind of reminds me of "puttering" or "putzing" which I have heard used in this sense in the U.S.  I don't know if "pootling" would ever come out of my mouth though!

Answer (score 7):

If you had a flat tire on your car, you could say, my car **hobbled** along till the next exit where I could get the flat fixed. (To indicate a personification of your car being injured)

My car **thumped** along as I continued on the highway with a flat tire.
(To give the reader a sense of the annoying sound the tire was making while you drove the car to the next exit to get the tire fixed or call for help in a secure area).

Answer (score 6):

**trundle**

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trundle)

> intransitive verb
> 1 : to progress by revolving
> 2 : to move on or as if on wheels

"Even through the city streets they trundled, reaching the warehouse at eight."

Comment: A lovely word :)  Not sure if it denotes slow movement in its intended meaning, but since it is an old word it often evokes the image of a slow moving car, cart, or horse-drawn wagon.  Could be useful depending on the intent.

Answer (score 4):

I think this one fits the bill nicely:

**tool**

> to drive a vehicle, especially in a relaxed way or without any specific purpose

*He spent the evening tooling around the town in his new car*.

[Macmillan]

*when intransitive, often followed by *along**

> to drive (a vehicle) or (of a vehicle) to be driven, esp in a leisurely or casual style.

[Collins]

EDIT: Thanks to @Criggie for suggesting **tootle**, which seems to me a better word in the given context.

> A leisurely journey.

*I was interested in a little more speed from the car than a tootle.*

[Lexico]

Comment: To me, "tooling" has never implied driving slowly.

Comment: Well, _Macmillan_ has it wrong then I guess. :)

Comment: Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Contemporary use in Charlie Daniels song "Uneasy Rider": "I was taking a trip out to LA, tooling along in my Chevrolet, toking on a number and digging on the radio."

Comment: I like this one

Comment: Hot Licks is right, and furthermore the OP specifically wants a word that reflects "especially in a way that is unexpected or looks out of place" which "tooling" does not.  In fact, to me, "tooling" is very similar to "cruising" except when you tool you don't necessarily even have a destination in mind, and if you do have one in mind, you don't necessarily care when you get there or even if you get there ...  (Unfortunately I cannot answer the question with another better word as the only ones that come to mind for this situation are adjectives, and they describe the driver, not the driving.)

Comment: I wonder if "tootling" is related to tooling

Comment: As KGIII pointed out, this word has been used this way.  I agree it may have fallen out of common usage over the years, or is maybe more used in some regions than others.  But I hope no one is downvoting this, it is a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: According to Merriam-Webster, "tool" as an intransitive verb means "drive" or "ride". No implication of slowness. Nothing in the Charlie Daniels quote from KGIII indicates that the narrator isn't driving at freeway speeds.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to crawling, a car can **creep**.

> That car up ahead was just creeping along. She wondered what was wrong with it.

Comment: This is what Tesla calls it.  They have a creep mode that causes the car to slowly move forward when you release the brake.

Answer (score 1):

slowpoke

[from Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/slowpoke)

> someone who moves slowly or more slowly than others

Comment: "Poking along" is another good phrase.  I don't know if I would refer to the car as a slowpoke, but maybe the driver.